# Where does npm -g store version

Tags: npm

When I install a package globally using `npm` - where does it store the version number I requested? I don't see a package.json file somwhere.

Example: I execute: `npm i -g eslint@3.4.0`. Where is the information saved I requested version 3.4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM stores it in the installed module's `package.json` file.

If you look in an installed module's `package.json`, you will see that the JSON package will have been extended to include a number of keys prefixed with `_`. For example:

```
"_from": "@angular/core@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
"_id": "@angular/core@2.1.2",
"_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/core/-/core-2.1.2.tgz",
```

`_from` is the semver range - or specific version - that was specified when the module was installed and `_id` was the module version that was matched and installed, etc.